# Bloodbowl - throw a rock, roll for injury or casualty?

Tags: blood-bowl

We use the 5.0 living rulebook. The exact wording for the event is the following:

> Throw a Rock: An enraged fan hurls a large rock at 
>   one of the players on the opposing team. Each 
>   coach rolls a D6 and adds their FAME (see page 
>   18) to the roll. The fans of the team that rolls higher 
>   are the ones that threw the rock. In the case of a tie 
>   a rock is thrown at each team! Decide randomly 
>   which player in the other team was hit (only players 
>   on the pitch are eligible) and roll for the effects of 
>   the injury straight away. No Armour roll is required.

I was under the impression this meant I had to roll on the injury table first, with the possibility to get a casualty table follow-up, for two reasons:

- The rule clearly states the armour role should be skipped, but does not mention the same for the injury roll.
- It is clear that there should be a roll, even in a one-off (no campaign or tournament) match. Those matches don't use the casualty table.

My opponent was under the impression I needed to roll casualty straight away, because the rule states to roll for injury effect, not for injury. The only spectator agreed, so I agreed to do it that way, but I would like to know if that was correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always roll for injury first.

Roll against casualty table if injury roll result is 10-12.

This is similar what you do when a player gets pushed or knocked off the pitch and gets beat up by the fans.

My rule interpretation:
The rule would most likely also say "No Armour roll is required and No Injury Roll is required" if the intent was to go directly to the casualty table.

Comment: I'm only familiar with the computer version of Bloodbowl, but it seems like this must be the logic it uses. It's very rare for a model to be taken off of the pitch on account of this, but I have seen it.

Comment: That's what I thought... Thanks! Do you know of any official clarifications or errata that mention it, by any chance? I wasn't able to find any.

Comment: No reference that I can find, but like Discord said, the CPU game is using injury rolls first.  I've also seen the CPU game "stun" players which means there was not a casualty roll.  I'll see if I can create a log of the event from a game if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late, but the interpretation above is correct. I play the game on Fumbbl and on tabletop and in both environments we treat a rock in the same way as for instance a block that broke armour (without damage modifiers)